# Oracle Deadlock resource name interpretation

Tags: oracle, deadlock, database-deadlocks, oracle19c

I got a ORA-00060 deadlock detected error and the wait for graph says there is a dead lock on resource
TX-00290010-00015F75-00000000-00000000 how to interpret this resource? Can we get the table name/rowid information from this?

Comment: Can you post more of the trace file? When I've investigated ORA-00060 trace files in the past, there is usually an OBJECT_ID or something in the file that will point to a table, bitmap index, etc.